# Чем чревато нажатие кнопки Introspect database в DataGrip?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datagrip

Я работаю в `DataGrip`, подключен к серверу с базами данных `microsoft sql server`. Слева у меня не отображается ни одна таблица из баз данных. Так же нет подсказок по вводу названий таблиц. У меня постоянно горит кнопка `introspect database`. Я так понимаю, если нажму ее, то вся информация об этой базе/таблицах и тд подгрузится ко мне на пк и все подсказки появятся и таблицы будут отображаться. Это так?

Как это повлияет на сервер/базу данных? Это почти прод и сломать что либо не очень хочется.

Comment: ну  так подгрузится то информаиця о таблицах, а не информация, содержащаяся в них, в чем проблема-то? на сервер баз данных повлиятся может update, delete, truncate и drop, врядли получение информации о схеме БД к этому каким либо образом отноится

Comment: @teran Я так же предполагаю, думаю, ВРЯДЛИ повлияет, но я хотел в этом убедиться. Вдруг там какие то системные таблицы по этому поводу решат обновиться или типо того. Хочу узнать наверняка.

Comment: @teran Спасибо за полезный совет. Думаю ваш ответ явно полезен для всего комьюнити stackoverflow и если у кого либо возникнет подобный вопрос он точно будет знать, что нужно прочесть документацию.

Comment: так вы прочли документацию?

Comment: Ничего касательно introspect database я в ней не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introspect database - это процесс получения метаданных об объектах, чтобы потом использовать эту информавцию для отображения, навигации, подсказок. Конечно, никаких апдейтов интроспекция не запускает и не может запускать. Это абсолютно безопасный процесс.